# Weak* and pointwise convergence of measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose I have a sequence of bounded measures $\{\mu_{k}\} \subset \mathcal{M}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ with
$$\forall \phi \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R}), \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\mu_{k}(x) \to \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\mu(x) .$$ Is it true that on any open $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $$ \mu_{k}(U) \to \mu(U)? $$
and therefore that $\mu_{k}(x) \to \mu(x)$ for any $x \in U$?

I thought we could prove it by taking $\phi = \phi_{n}$ approximating the indicator function of any open set $U$. Then the integral convergence would give
$$ \int_{U}\mu_{k}(x) \to \int_{U}\mu(x), $$ i.e. that $\mu_{k}(U) \to \mu(U)$. But this seems wrong becauase I dont think weak* convergence of measures implies pointwise convergence, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you do the approximation you get $\liminf \mu_n(U) \geq \mu(U)$. This is known as the portmanteau theorem.

Comment: @Kakashi ah I see thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example ... $\mu_k = \delta_k$, where $\delta_k$ is the unit point mass at $k$.  Then (easy) $\int\phi(x) \mu_k(dx) \to 0$ for all $\phi$ with compact support.  But $\mu_k(\mathbb R) = 1 \not\to 0$.

---

Similar example, but everything is in $[0,1]$.
$\mu_k = \delta_{1/k}$ and $\mu = \delta_0$.  Then $\int\phi(x) \mu_k(dx)=\phi(1/k) \to \phi(0) = \int\phi(x)\,\mu(dx)$ for all continuous $\phi$.  But for the open set $U = (0,1)$ we have $\mu_k(U)=1 \not\to 0 = \mu(U)$.
[We only get one direction of inequality, as noted by Kakashi.  And the other direction for closed sets.]

Comment: Right right thank you